# How to use cursor in mongodb nodejs driver 3.0?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cursor

With mongodb nodejs driver version 2, I could do the following:

```
const cursor = db.collection('names').find()
```

and then iterate as follow:

```
cursor.forEach((doc)=> {
    console.log(doc)
}, err=> {
    client.close()
})
```

Somehow, in version 3, it looks like cursor is not iterable. 
Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT: Full code**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const assert = require('assert')
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name', { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client)=> {
    assert.equal(null, err)
    const db = client.db()
    const cursor = db.collection('names').find()
    cursor.forEach(doc=>{
        // Somehow, the code doesn't seem to enter this block of code
        console.log(doc)
    }, err => {
       // but later enters here to close the database connection.
       client.close()
    })
})
```

Comment: Try with `collection('names').find({}).toArray((error, docs) => { ...`

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla I'm trying to use a cursor. Your suggestion will fetch all the data in memory before displaying them which is completely different from how a cursor operates

Comment: Yeah, but you can try that first to check if you are recieving the documents, if not then you are sure the problem is not in the `forEach`

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla Yeah I now understand what you said. `collection('names').find({}).toArray((error, docs) => { ...` works just fine and returns data.

Comment: I tried your code and it works without a problem. What error/output do you have?

Comment: @shvetsovdm are you using `"mongodb": "3.1.4"`? Cause my code doesn't work with this particular version. It works fine with the version `2.0` so I'm thinking something has changed but not sure what. Thanks for taking the taking to try my code.

Comment: "mongodb": "3.1.4" exactly this version. I assume the problem with your collection/db. Can you create a new one db with brand new simple collection and confirm that the error is persist?

Comment: and what your version of mongodb? You can check with `mongod --version`

Comment: `mongod --version` gives `db version v4.0.0`. Sure I will try as you suggested @shvetsovdm

Comment: @lomse any luck?

Comment: @shvetsovdm Nah,  what is your mongodb server version?

Comment: @lomse `db version v3.4.7`

Comment: The code above works with "mongodb@3.2.2" package and "mongo:4.0.8" docker image